# apache2 response size limit - json data

Tags: apache, size, response, limit

I'm having problems when trying to send a json response of more than 4096 bytes using apache2 / php.
I guess it is some parameter I have to change, but I can not figure it out ( apache or php ? )

Thanks.
Regards.
Facundo.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.
It is related with PHP5.
All I've to do is change the parameter "output_buffering" in the file php.ini to have a value of 8192 ( or whatever you need ).

Regards.
Facundo.